# CSWP query - list all items in a list AND list a spesific item in another list

Tags: search, content-search-web-part, search-query, cswp

Is there a way to combine two list in cswp?

1. Get all list items from "car" list
2. Get a spesific item from "plane" list

> (path:"company/Lists/car"  (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")) 
>   AND (path:"company/Lists/plane" (IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem") title:"airbus")

Both lists have the same default columns!

If I write :

> path:"company/Lists/car"
>   path:"company/Lists/plane"

it returns all items in both lists..

**Update solution**

Found out that I had to use OR instead of AND in my query.  (query text) OR (Query text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(IsDocument:"True" OR contentclass:"STS_ListItem")
AND
(
(path:"company/Lists/car")
OR
(path:"company/Lists/plane" title:"airbus")
)